# Make a Dropdownmenu with CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I would like to make a Dropdownmenu, but It is not that easy, because I am working with panels.
This is my menu. I've got the nav= menu and then I got a panel for the menu and one for the submenu. The submenupanel is not displayed by default.
Now I wan't a block which comes down, when I hover over the pnlMenu.

```
 <div id="wrapper_menu">
        <div id="menuicon">
            <div class="menubar" id="menubar-top"></div>
            <div class="menubar" id="menubar-mid"></div>
            <div class="menubar" id="menubar-bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <nav id="menu">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubmenu" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </asp:Panel>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

This is my css code which I have. What I also need is a selector which changes an other div. I don't know if it is really posssible that it works like that, but isn't anything which should display the Dropdownmenu, I only wanted to look if I can select like that.

```
    #pnlMenu .menu_link:hover #pnlSubmenu .submenu_link {
    height:50px;
   display:block;
}
```

Because I am working with the masterpage, there's code which gets generated.
This is my html code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will not work

```
    #pnlMenu .menu_link:hover #pnlSubmenu .submenu_link {
    height:50px;
   display:block;
}
```

because it assumes that `#pnlSubmenu` is a child of `.menu_link` which it is not.

In fact `#pnlSubmenu` is a sibling of `#pnlMenu` so you may need to rethink the approach.

I suspect that the interactivity may need javascript given the HTML's current structure as there is **no CSS selector** that will allow you to affect the submenu div by hovering a link in the the first menu div

Comment: But is there a way to do that. I found that it is possible with a ~ but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not given the current HTML. The `~` general sibling selector requires that the link and the submenu div have a common parent...which they don't.